# Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I have an issue launching firefox with the above error message. When I tried some of the solutions posted in this forum I receive the error message

> user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

How do I launch firefox without requiring any profiles ? I mean its just a freaking internet browser and I need it for my exam. Help me please.

```
firefox -ProfileManager
firefox -P
```

Returns

> Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or
>   inaccessible

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx ~/.mozilla/firefox/; ls -l ~/.mozilla/firefox/` please.

Answer (score 4):

Usually I fix this by restoring correct rights on corresponding catalogs with:

```
sudo chown $USER: -R ~/.cache/mozilla/ ~/.mozilla/firefox/
```

Comment: this happened to me after using ~ as a docker volume and docker crashing

Comment: @N0rbert I have the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04. I use the command as you suggested and getting an error **chown: cannot acess '/home/muusername/.cache/mozilla/': No such file or directory**. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kill all currently running process

   ```
   killall firefox
   killall thunderbird
   ```
2. Remove the cache Files

   Note: Backup them before removing.

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.mozilla/
   rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla/
   ```

   Try running Firefox now:
       `$ firefox`

   If it still doesn't work then proceed further.
3. Change the ownership of the following folders

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache/.mozilla/
   sudo chown -R $USER ~/.mozilla/
   ```

   **If the above step is NOT successful, then try the following**

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/.mozilla/
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.mozilla/
   ```

   **If the above step is NOT successful, then try following**

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/.mozilla/
   sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.mozilla/
   ```
4. If all the above steps NOT successful, Then change entire cache folder permission

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache
   sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/
   ```

Comment: `chmod 777` is never the solution.

Comment: I suggest to replace chmod with: chmod -R u+rwX,g+rwX file